# Bash Script to copy from external drive to Box folder

Tags: bash, scripting, drive

Trying to write a bash script to copy a large number of files from an external drive into separate directories based on a subject id.

I've included the script I've written below.

I get the following error:

```
cat: /Volumes/Seagate: No such file or directory
cat: Backup: No such file or directory
cat: Plus: No such file or directory
cat: Drive/Subject_List.txt: No such file or directory
```

When I try to copy a single file at a time using the terminal, it copies using the exact command I've put in this script. I'm not sure why it's not recognizing the directory when I try and use it in the script below. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash

#A bash script to copy the structural and functional files into the HCP_Entropy folder

#subject list

SUBJECT_LIST="/Volumes/Seagate/Backup/Plus/Drive/Subject_List.txt

for j in $(cat ${SUBJECT_LIST}); do 

echo ${j}

cp /Volumes/Seagate\ Backup\ Plus\ Drive/HCP_DATA/Structural/{j}/unprocessed/3T/T1w_MPR1/${j}_3T_T1w_MPR1.nii.gz /Users/myname/Box/HCP_Entropy/BEN/${j}/anat

done
```

Comment: Whenever you have arguments, like these file names, that have space in them, you need quotes around them. The existing answer points to that for one part of your script, the extra error you report is of the same type: everywhere you use variables, make sure they're inside double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

the line

```
$SUBJECT_LIST=/Volumes/Seagate\ Backup\ Plus\ Drive/Subject_List.txt
```

is bogus.

to assign values to a variable, you must not add the `$` specifier.
a token starting with `$` will be *expanded*, so `$SUBJECT_LIST=...` will first be expanded to `=...` (since you haven't assigned anything to the `SUBJECT_LIST` variable yet it is empty).

the proper way would be:

```
SUBJECT_LIST="/Volumes/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/Subject_List.txt"
```

(this uses quotes instead of escaping each space, which i find much more readable)

you also need to quote variables in case they contain spaces, else they might be interpreted by the command (`cp`) as multiple arguments.

```
for j in $(cat "${SUBJECT_LIST}"); do
 # ...
done
```

and of course, you should check whether the source file actually exists, just like the destination directory.

```sh
indir="/Volumes/Seagate Backup Plus Drive"
SUBJECT_LIST="${indir}/Subject_List.txt"
cat "${SUBJECT_LIST}" | while read j; do
  infile="${indir}/HCP_DATA/Structural/${j}/unprocessed/3T/T1w_MPR1/${j}_3T_T1w_MPR1.nii.gz"
  outdir="/Users/myname/Box/HCP_Entropy/BEN/${j}/anat"

  mkdir -p "${outdir}"
  if [ -e "${infile}" ]; then
    cp -v "${infile}" "${outdir}"
  else
   echo "missing file ${infile}" 1>&2
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I made the following change, and now I get a different error:  cat: /Volumes/Seagate: No such file or directory
cat: Backup: No such file or directory
cat: Plus: No such file or directory
cat: Drive/Subject_List.txt: No such file or directory.      Any insights?

Comment: i've updated the answer. (i seriously hope this is not one of meandering questions that just add a "but now it does this" whenever three is a new answer)